# При прокрутки слайдера пропадают слайды. Как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Слайдер сделал с помощью Slick.js. В слайдере всегда должно отображаться три слайда, но при прокрутки слайды "улетают", а вместо них пустое место.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем  тут  загвоздка?

```
 '$('.starring_2').slick({
    variableWidth: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    nextArrow: '<img src="./img/next_arrow.png">',
    prevArrow: '<img src="./img/prev_arrow.png">'
});'




'<div class="starring_2">
                <div class="actor_1">
                    <img src="img/actorphoto_1_960.png" alt="actorphoto_1">
                    <h3>актер</h3>
                    <p>ЗОЯ БЕРБЕР</p>
                </div>
                <div class="actor_2">
                    <img src="img/actorphoto_2_960.png" alt="actorphoto_2">
                    <h3>актер</h3>
                    <p>ИЛЬЯ ГЛИННИКОВ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="actor_3">
                    <img src="img/actorphoto_3_960.png" alt="actorphoto_3">
                    <h3>актер</h3>
                    <p>ВАДИМ ДЕМЧОГ</p>
                </div>
                 <div class="actor_1">
                    <img src="img/actorphoto_1_960.png" alt="actorphoto_1">
                    <h3>актер</h3>
                    <p>ЗОЯ БЕРБЕР</p>
                </div>
                <div class="actor_2">
                    <img src="img/actorphoto_2_960.png" alt="actorphoto_2">
                    <h3>актер</h3>
                    <p>ИЛЬЯ ГЛИННИКОВ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="actor_3">
                    <img src="img/actorphoto_3_960.png" alt="actorphoto_3">
                    <h3>актер</h3>
                    <p>ВАДИМ ДЕМЧОГ</p>
                </div>
            </div>'






 '  .starring_2 {
    width: 650px;
    margin: 25px 0 0 500px;
}
.actor_1{
    height: 379px;
    width: 197px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 626px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.actor_2{
    margin: 8px 0 0 24px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 380px;
    width: 198px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.actor_3{
    margin: 8px 0 0 24px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 380px;
    width: 198px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}'
```

[image: слайдер по умолчанию]

[image: слайдер после прокрутки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Margin` слева нужно убрать, иначе слайды сдвигаются.

```
<div class="starring_2">
  <div class="actor_1">
    <img src="img/actorphoto_1_960.png" alt="actorphoto_1">
    <h3>актер</h3>
    <p>ЗОЯ БЕРБЕР</p>
  </div>
  <div class="actor_2">
    <img src="img/actorphoto_2_960.png" alt="actorphoto_2">
    <h3>актер</h3>
    <p>ИЛЬЯ ГЛИННИКОВ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="actor_3">
    <img src="img/actorphoto_3_960.png" alt="actorphoto_3">
    <h3>актер</h3>
    <p>ВАДИМ ДЕМЧОГ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="actor_1">
    <img src="img/actorphoto_1_960.png" alt="actorphoto_1">
    <h3>актер</h3>
    <p>ЗОЯ БЕРБЕР</p>
  </div>
  <div class="actor_2">
    <img src="img/actorphoto_2_960.png" alt="actorphoto_2">
    <h3>актер</h3>
    <p>ИЛЬЯ ГЛИННИКОВ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="actor_3">
    <img src="img/actorphoto_3_960.png" alt="actorphoto_3">
    <h3>актер</h3>
    <p>ВАДИМ ДЕМЧОГ</p>
  </div>
</div>

.starring_2 {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 500px;
}

.actor_1 {
  height: 379px;
  width: 197px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.actor_2 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 380px;
  width: 198px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.actor_3 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 380px;
  width: 198px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
$('.starring_2').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  nextArrow: '<img src="./img/next_arrow.png">',
  prevArrow: '<img src="./img/prev_arrow.png">'
});
```

[Рабочий вариант.](https://codepen.io/Cheg/pen/GEBZVj)

Comment: Да, `margin` был здесь лишним, как и настройка слайдера `variableWidth: true,`
Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @AndreyBal' , по сути, можно убрать и `width` у слайдов, т.к. `slick.js` сам высчитает нужную ширину.